# Huge sparse matrix - vector multiplication

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, blas

I'm looking for a library to do huge Sparse Matrix x Vector multiplication.
The matrix itself will almost fill the RAM.

I've found Eigen3, OSKI and some basic Sparse BLAS implementations.

Are there other options? 
How can I choose between them ?

Edit: There is also Intel's MKL

Answer (score 1):

There are the linear algebra routines in Trilinos and Petsc. Also, most finite element libraries like deal.II or Dune have this capability.

Comment: Don't they use seom more low level library under the hood?

Comment: Not necessarily. Trilinos and Petsc have their own parallel matrix structures. As for deal.II, it is your choice, whether you use their own structures or Trilinos, or Petsc